# Getting Requested unknown parameter 'Gross A.ROI' for row 0, column 7 in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Using Datatable cdn links:-

`<scriptsrc="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> <scriptsrc="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> <linkrel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" /> <linkrel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />`

Datatable logic:-

```
$('#datatable_plreports').DataTable({
        "data": jsonData,

        "autoWidth": true,
        "info": false,
        "paging": true,
        "searching": true,

        "columns":
            [
                { data: 'VendorName' },
                { data: 'VendorCode' },
                { data: 'Start Date' },
                { data: 'Fund' },
                { data: 'WeekPL' },
                { data: 'GrossPL' },
                { data: 'GrossROI' },
                { data: 'Gross A.ROI' },
                { data: 'WeeksTraded' },
            ],
    });
```

I have created a Datatable and appended data to that datatabable successfully but the `Gross A.ROI` column is throwing the error like this`Requested unknown parameter 'Gross A.ROI' for row 0, column 7`  but I don't know why this error is coming

[image: Error]

And I'm getting this `Gross A.ROI` column name from service and except this column all the data is appending to the datatable like below example

[image: Appending data]

In the above img except `Gross A.ROI` column all data is coming.

And the data is coming like this

[image: Data]

I have given the column name correctly but I don't know why this error is coming suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: try `{ data: 'Gross A\\.ROI' },`. In other words, escape the `.`.